# Distribution of points in a homogeneous PPP

Tags: probability, geometry, stochastic-processes

PPP holds some important properties. However, my question is whether the positions of the points in a homogeneous PPP are independent? Equivalently, are the points in a homogeneous PPP distributed independently in the domain?

Is there any reference that clearly states this property (not conditioned on the number of points in a prescribed area size)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PPP stands for Poisson point process, right? You may take the one dimensional case, i.e a jump process. The position of previous jump will influence the position of next jump

Comment: Does it? Given the position of one point, the next one will be placed in a memoryless manner (exponentially), so there is no difference.

Comment: In a memoryless manner, but after the given point. Is $E(X_2)$ equal to $E(X_2 | X_1)$?

Comment: I think memory-less doesn't imply Markovian (one step memory) as you suggested. So, in the exponential distribution the outcome is not affected by previous history. (Thank you for having this discussion)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, what I wanted to say is that, suppose we have a Poisson process with intensity $1$, $X_1$ is the first jump time and $X_2$ is the second jump time. Then $E(X_2) = 2$ and $E(X_2 |X_1) = X_1 + 1$, so I think $X_2$ is not independent of $X_1$